# Three.JS 3D Model Added but it's not visible

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-modelling

I'm trying to add a 3D Model to my website. I'm using three.js. I tried all I could but I can not make the 3d model visible. In the network tab in developer tools I can see that MTL and OBJ files are loaded but the page is just blank. I tried with 3 different 3D models but same issue persists. I would apricate any help.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>3D Model</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/87/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="/js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
<script src="/js/MTLLoader.js"></script>

<script>
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee); // Light gray background color
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
    scene.add(light);

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    var MTLLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    MTLLoader.setPath("/models/Silivri001/");
    MTLLoader.load("odm_textured_model_geo.mtl", function(material) {
        material.preload();

        // Set the path for the OBJLoader
        var OBJLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        OBJLoader.setMaterials(material);
        OBJLoader.setPath("/models/Silivri001/"); // Set the correct path here

        OBJLoader.load("odm_textured_model_geo.obj", function(object) {
             object.position.set(0, -60, 0); // Adjust the values as needed
        object.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
            scene.add(object);
        });
    });

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    animate();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding an ambient light and playing with the scaling of the object. It might need too big or too small

Comment: I tried various ambient lights and played with the scale to no avail. Still I can not see the model.

Comment: Does the console show you any errors?

Comment: Nope. No errors. It says "THREE.WebGLRenderer 87" and "OBJLoader: 1282.401123046875 ms" and that's all.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the obj file? Is this code going to run if I copy-paste it into my editor? I mean is it complete and run-able?

Comment: I could share it like this https://elipptic5g.com/models/Silivri001/odm_textured_model_geo.obj
I don't know if that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the 3D model. I was able to load it successfully. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the CDN of the files to the more modern UNPKG CDN, loading all the `three.js` files from there, and also loading the 3D model from the URL you pasted on the comment, I was able to load the file successfully. I also tweaked the position of the object to -5 and the scale to 0.05. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>3D Model</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: white;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.147.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.147.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.147.0/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.147.0/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>

    <script>
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10000);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);


        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0xeeeeee); // Light gray background color
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const light = new THREE.AmbientLight();
        scene.add(light);

        const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        directionalLight.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
        scene.add(directionalLight);

        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

        var MTLLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

        MTLLoader.load("https://elipptic5g.com/models/Silivri001/odm_textured_model_geo.mtl", function (material) {
            material.preload();
            console.log(material)

            // Set the path for the OBJLoader
            var OBJLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            OBJLoader.setMaterials(material);


            OBJLoader.load("https://elipptic5g.com/models/Silivri001/odm_textured_model_geo.obj", function (object) {
                object.position.set(0, -5, 0); // Adjust the values as needed
                object.scale.set(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
                object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

                console.log(object)
                scene.add(object);
            });
        });

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        }
        animate();

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is what I see in my browser:

[image]